# Are auto generated IDs preserved when backing up google datastore from recovery?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have an app engine project that uses google data store as its persistence layer.

There is no backup mechanism planned yet.

I was reading that you could set up backups that can be scheduled to run at intervals and backed up to GCS.

A lot of entities in my datastore depends on auto generated IDs for referencing some parent entities. While the system is not entirely an RDBMS structure there are few entities that lookup other entities through their auto generated IDs.

Now when the system gets restored to a previous snapshot do the IDs get restored or not ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use our restore functionality then the previously auto-assigned IDs are reserved again during the restore process.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot. Thats a relief :)